# Target somehow doesn't get created

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gnu

I have a target that doesn't get create but it's immediate dependencies do. And there's not error message.

Here is the makefile:

```
PREFIX?=/home/jenia/learn-c-the-hard-way
CFLAGS=-g -Wall -I${PREFIX}/lib/include
LDFLAGS=-L${PREFIX}/lib
INSTALL_DIR=/home/jenia/learn-c-the-hard-way/apps

all: set-manipulation
set-manipulation: main.o

install: all
    install -d $(INSTALL_DIR)/set-manipulation
    install set-manipulation $(INSTALL_DIR)/set-manipulation

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f set-manipulation
    rm -rf *.dSYM
```

I end up with the `main.o` file but NOT the `set-manipulation` file which is the name of the program.

Like in a bigger program I want to create the object files first and then the program. Like

```
all: my-amazing-prog

my-amazing-prog: A.o B.o C.o D.o

...
```

And then end up with the files:

```
A.o, 
B.o, 
C.o, 
D.o, 
my-amazing-prog
```

So I don't understand why I'm having trouble in this case to create both the object.o files and then the prgram that depends on them.

P.S.

Just in case, here is the directory structure:

```
  /home/jenia/learn-c-the-hard-way/lib:
  drwxr-xr-x  2 jenia jenia 4096 Nov  1 12:47 include
  -rwxr-xr-x  1 jenia jenia 6804 Nov  1 12:47 set_theory.a -- 50
  -rwxr-xr-x  1 jenia jenia 9664 Nov  1 12:47 set_theory.so -- 11


  /home/jenia/learn-c-the-hard-way/lib/include:
  -rw-r--r--  1 jenia jenia   85 Nov  1 12:47 bag.h -- 3
  -rw-r--r--  1 jenia jenia   64 Nov  1 12:47 new.h -- 2
  -rw-r--r--  1 jenia jenia   92 Nov  1 12:47 object.h -- 3
  -rw-r--r--  1 jenia jenia  318 Nov  1 12:47 set.h -- 16
```

Comment: the Makefile you posted is incomplete, as there is no rule to create `main.o`. please post a [mcve]

Comment: @m.s.: you don't usually need an explicit rule to create `main.o` from a source file such as `main.c`.  Of course, it would be more convincing if the directory listing showed the existence of `main.c`, but that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a rule telling make how to create `set-manipulation` from `main.o`. This part:

```
set-manipulation: main.o
```

only specifies the dependency, but no commands. Use, e.g.

```
set-manipulation: main.o
      $(CC) -o "$@" main.o
```

I'm pretty sure that if

```
my-amazing-prog: A.o B.o C.o D.o
```

does create `my-amazing-prog` you *do* have some commands associated with it. Make has some built-in rules to create a program `prog` from a single source file `prog.c`, maybe that is what you have seen working somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks. I changed the makefile like this: `set-manipulation: main.o
 $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o "$@" main.o
`, but now the linker can't find either the header or the libraries. Here is example: `main.o: In function main':
/home/jenia/learn-c-the-hard-way/objects-orientated-c/set-manipulations/main.c:9: undefined reference to Set'` Before, this error did not appear.

Comment: I edited the question to add the file structure of the libs and header files

Comment: Also, this is what the compiler outputs before the error message: `cc -g -Wall -I/home/jenia/learn-c-the-hard-way/lib/include   -c -o main.o main.c <NEW LINE>
cc -L/home/jenia/learn-c-the-hard-way/lib -g -Wall -I/home/jenia/learn-c-the-hard-way/lib/include -o "set-manipulation" main.o`

Comment: @JeniaIvanov That can't work; if linking you can't use the `-c` (compile only) option. Either link, or compile.